# call an async function out of another async function to run parallel

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a working async function as main code `(async function (){...});`, working with some inputs coming from reed contacts posting them into a cloud. All good so far.

Now I want to add the feature analyzing if a reed is open for more then x seconds. If so, I want to do something additionally but still listening to other inputs while that. So what I try is:

```
var threshold;

async function time(threshold){
  var sec = 0;
  var start = new Date(); //set time stamp
  while (sec < threshold){
      // take actual time
      var akt = new Date();
      // calc difference
      var diff = akt.getTime() - start.getTime();
      // calc secs from mills
      sec = Math.floor(diff / 1000);
  } 
  post threshold data to cloud;
  return "Threshold reached";
}

(async function () {

  reading reed permanent {

    if (reed === 1){
      post data to cloud;
      var call = time(20);
      console.log(call);
    }
  }
})();
```

I wan't the main function still listeing to new reed changes while the `time` loop should wait for the threshold and do it's job parallel.

But my code waits for the threshold to be reached before continuing.
How can I parallel them?

---

EDIT after Gibors help:

Now I stuck at the point verifying if the reed is still open or was closed meanwhile. I always get a `diff > threshold` even if the reed is closed in the meanwhile so that the timestamp should be newer...

````
var id = [];
if (value['contact'] === 1) {
              var bool = "false";
              id[device['manufacturer']] = new Date();
            } else if(value['contact'] === 0) {
              var bool = "true";
              id[device['manufacturer']] = new Date();
              setTimeout( () => {
                var akt = new Date();
                var diff = akt.getTime() - id[device['manufacturer']].getTime();
                if (diff > threshold) {

                  console.log("now: " + diff + "=" + akt.getTime() + "-" + id[device['manufacturer']].getTime());
                }
              }, threshold);
              /*var call = time (50);
              console.log(call);*/
            }
    ```
````

Comment: I don't see any asynchronous operations in your `time` function. So once it starts to run, it never yields execution back to the event loop.

Comment: you could simply use `setTimeout` rather  new implemented `time` function. however, don't await for time function, if you don't want to wait for it to complete.

Comment: @tehhowch seems `post threshold data to cloud;` is the async call.

Comment: Uh, oh, that `time()` function is just ugly, it blocks the whole thread for that time. Instead use `const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))`, then `await timer(20)`

Comment: @AZ_ the lack of async ops within the `while` was my point.

Comment: @tehhowch oh ok got it.

Comment: I don't get where to add @JonasWilms code.
adding `await timer(20)` to the async time function or in the main code? As I only want to post additional data if the reed opens more then 20 secs...

Comment: What "reed"? I'm really not sure what you are doing and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Simplified I start a routine which is listening for inputs. reed is a magnetic contact for e.g. your window to notice if it's open or closed. And every time one of these contacts is triggered I post a timeseries in the cloud.

If a reed/switch is triggered for more the x Seconds, I want to note that in the cloud too.

Answer (score 1):

First i'll explain what wrong with your code, and then i'll give you something I believe is a better and simpler solution:

Your `time` function is marked as async, but it actually does nothing asynch-ish. This effectively means that when the function "returns"- it actually returns a resolved promise. But the promise is created only at the end and resolves immediately, so it doesn't do its job to be async.

I believe something like this should work:

```
async function time(threshold){
   return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
     var sec = 0;
     var start = new Date(); //set time stamp
     while (sec < threshold){
        // take actual time
        var akt = new Date();
        // calc difference
        var diff = akt.getTime() - start.getTime();
        // calc secs from mills
        sec = Math.floor(diff / 1000);
     } 
     post threshold data to cloud;
     resolve("Threshold reached)";
   }
}
```

Now this will run in parallel, and `call` variable will only get the string "threshold reached" when promise is resolved- which means in your current code, the log you'll get is something like `Promise<pending>`.
To log only when its done (and do your other stuff), use the `.then` on the promise held by `call`.

One thing you should notice tho, is that you'll have to somehow sync between the `reed` status (which I didn't really get what it actually is but I think its irrelevant) and the promise status, because you want to do your post-timeout code when the 20 sec are over AND reed is still open, so you'll have to check it in your `.then` clause, or pass it to time function which will reject the promise if the `reed` status changes before time runs out, etc.

Now- for the simple solution: it seems to me you're way better off using the setTimeout function:

> The setTimeout() method sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once the timer expires.

So you can simply do something like this:

```
(async function () {

  reading reed permanent {

    if (reed === 1){
      post data to cloud;
      setTimeout( () => { if(reed still open) {/*do what you want after timeout*/}  }, 20 );
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: OK, that took me huge step further. Nut now I have exactly the problem, that I need to verify if the specific  reed is still open. For that I defined a array and store the timestamp in it. When the timeout is over, I want to verify if the timestamp is as old as the timeout or if it was changed in the meanwhile (because of closind the specific reed again... but somehow it doesn't work... and i'm clueless. --> I added the modified code above.

Comment: @Tom this is a bit hard to answer, as I do not know which environment / framework you working in, you data flow, etc so it is hard to give something specific. In general, i'd try something along the lines of event emitting- for example - emit an event when timeout is reached, and add a listener somewhere in the scope where you have access to the **current** reed status. Then you could check in the event function if reed is still open then you raise up a flag which is constantly checked and if it is raised- you do your stuff and bring it back down for the next iteration.

Comment: @Tom Again, this is very general but I hope you got the idea. If not or you can't implement event emitting in your code- I suggest you open a new question with more details about the task in general, the environment you're workin in and describe the new problem better and we can try and help there :)
Also if my answer helped you, don't forget to tick the green V and mark it as accepted :D